# Generate charts in webapp with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, charts

I need to display charts in a web application developped with spring mvc. What's the best library to do that?

Prepare data and generate charts with JFreechart in spring controller or use javascript library like jquery plugin flot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using jQuery charts - the [jqPlot plugin](http://www.jqplot.com/) for example. I fill the model in the spring controller, and then initialize the chart with it. You'd have to mix javascript and JSTL.